# Is there any way to save values in table that doesn't have primary key? In cakephp 3

Tags: cakephp-3.x

I have table without primary key. Is there any way to save data into table 
using cakephp3?

Comment: We are here to help you solve your issues. Rather then completely answering and writing code for you. Please let us us know what efforts have you put to do this.

Comment: @Ms.Nehal Are you clear about the question? i think it doesn'e need any code to answer... i'm just asking is there any way to do?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, if you want to update rows based on a condition try `updateAll($fields, $conditions)`.  No primary key needed.

http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html#bulk-updates